# Groups and Subgroups - Confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all subgroups (and their orders) of the group $<\mathbb{Z}_{30}, +_{30}>$.

This material is new to me. I know what a subgroup is by reading the definition, but what does the problem mean by 'orders'? So, for the definition of a subgroup, if H $\subseteq G$ (and $(G, *)$ is a group) and $H$ is a group with the same binary operation $*$, then $H$ is called a $\textit{subgroup}$.

But.. how do I go about finding every single subgroup? And what is meant by 'orders'?

**Order == Cardinality == Size of the Set/Group**

Right, now how do we find all of the subgroups?

**RESOLVED - See comments**

Comment: "order means the size of the group" - I don't know where you're comment just went, but okay. I thought that what the word cardinality was for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any group of the form $\langle \mathbb Z_n, +_n\rangle$ is *cyclic* (meaning there is some $g\in \mathbb Z_n$ such that $g$ generates the entire group: $\langle g\rangle = \mathbb Z_n)$.

The order of $\mathbb Z_n$ *is* $n$, meaning it contains exactly $n$ elements.

A subgroup with $m$ elements has order $m$.

Every subgroup of a cyclic group is also cyclic, meaning that if $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$, then there is an element $h\in H$ such that $h$ generates all of $H$.

For a cyclic group of order $n$, there exists a unique (one and only one) subgroup of order $m$ for every $m$ that divides $n$, and for any $r$ such that $r$ does NOT divide $n$, no subgroup of order $r$ exists.

So in the case of $\mathbb Z_{30}$, since $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30$ all divide $30$, you can expect to find for each divisor $m$, a unique subgroup whose order is equal to $m$.

Of course, $\{0\}$ is the trivial subgroup of order $1$, and $\mathbb Z_{30}$ is a subgroup of itself, and of order $30$.

Six additional subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{30}$ exist.

Comment: So $\left [ 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30 \right ]$ are the orders of the subgroups of $Z_{30}$. A subgroup of order $m$ is generated by $a^{\frac{n}{m}}$. So for example we pick the subgroup of order $2$, then $a^{\frac{n}{m}} = a^{15}$. So..shouldn't this be $\left \{ 1,2,3,\cdots, a^{15}\right \}$? But that isn't of order $2$..

Comment: @Ozera: Since we're using additive notation, we'd rather write $a^{15}$ as $15a$, or just 15. The subgroup generated by $15$ is just the multiples of 15, i.e., $\{0,15\}$, and has order 2.

Comment: @Kundor Ah, the multiples of $15$. Of course. Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: Does this all make sense now, Ozera? You'll have a subgroup of order 3 (multiples of 10), of order $5$ (multiples of 6), etc.

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Typo in your answer: *six* additional subgroups exist. (Eight total, and you had just talked about two.)

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}&\;\;\left(\Bbb Z_{30}\,,\,+_{30}\right)\;\;\text{is a cyclic (additive) group}\\{}\\
&\;\;\text{In any cyclic group of order $\;n\;$, for any divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$ there exists a unique subgroup (also cyclic, of course) or order $\;d\;$ }\end{align*}$$

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, this along with the other answers helped me complete the problem.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#fundamental_thoeorem_of_fin) The group $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ is isomorphic to
$$
\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5
$$
since $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.  You can find all the subgroups by taking factors.  The "order" of a group is just how many elements are in it.